# How to fetch script tag with value from html

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I am working on lambda function with nodejs. In which I hit one http url which returns http response. This response contains few script tag and I want to get it.

```
const https = require('https')

// const json = require('json')
let url = "https://test.com"   

exports.handler = async function(event) {
  const promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    https.get(url, (res) => {
        resolve(res.statusCode)
        console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
          console.log('###############################################');
          console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
        });
        
      }).on('error', (e) => {
        reject(Error(e))
      })
    })
  return promise

}
```

it return something like below code.

```
<meta property="fb:pages" content="400601983320296">
<link href="https:/test,minify-1.cms" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var isAdaptive = '1', isPremium = '';
    </script>
    
    <script>
        var arrArticleList = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
        
        var arrPromoList = [];
    </script>
```

I want to extract this script tag from response without using any npm module. because I am developing code directly on lambda console.

Thanks

Comment: Write your own, basic HTML parser or bite the bullet and import an existing NPM module and package your code externally for deployment to Lambda.

Comment: As @jarmod states, you can write your own parser code, but that's gonna take a lot more time than just uploading the dependency. I'm curious as to why you don't want to upload a dependency?

Comment: It might also be possible to do what you want with a pre-configured Lambda layer that itself includes the dependencies that you want. Then you simply configure your function to use that Lambda layer. I would try that option.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my implementation (you could probably also use Regex instead of this approach):

```
const https = require('https')
let url = "https://test.com"   

async function t() {
  const promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    https.get(url, (res) => {
        resolve(res.statusCode)
        console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
          console.log('###############################################');

          // get scripts
          let s = chunk
          const scripts = [];
          while (s.indexOf("<script") != -1 && s.indexOf("</script>") != -1) {
            let f = s.indexOf("<script");
            let l = s.indexOf("</script>")+9;
            scripts.push(s.slice(f, l))
            s = s.slice(l)
          }
          console.log(scripts)
          //

        });
        
      }).on('error', (e) => {
        reject(Error(e))
      })
    })
  return promise
}
```